# Traversing down a directory till I find a certain file in C#

Tags: c#, file-io, directory, traversal

I have a list of directories - these folders are all websites - and I need to write some code to traverse down each one of these directories until I find the `index.html` file.  When I find `index.html`, I need to write the entire path out to a text file.  I know how to do basic file I/O, such as writing data to a file, but what I'm getting hung up on is how to traverse down each directory until I hit a certain file, then capture that entire path, then continue on to the next folder/directory.  I'm not sure where to start and I was hoping I could find some guidance from you all.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a [function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143316.aspx) that can do that  : **Directory.GetFiles Method (String, String, SearchOption)**

Returns the names of files (including their paths) that match the specified search pattern in the specified directory, using a value to determine whether to search subdirectories.

Comment: Please switch to `EnumerateFiles()` instead of using `GetFiles()` (which would mean take Matthews answer).

Comment: This is what I ultimately used.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to find the very first instance of a file with a particular name and stop searching immediately when you find it, this is the most efficient approach.

It uses the `SearchOption.AllDirectories` option to tell it to recursively descend the directories for you.

```
string rootPath = "X:\\MyRoot";
string targetPattern = "index.html";

string fullPath = Directory
                 .EnumerateFiles(rootPath, targetPattern, SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                 .FirstOrDefault();

if (fullPath != null)
    Console.WriteLine("Found " + fullPath);
else
    Console.WriteLine("Not found");
```

(Note that if you use `Directory.GetFiles()` it will iterate over all possible folders, even if it has already found an instance of the target file, whereas `EnumerateFiles()` allows you to stop iterating as soon as the file is found.)

This uses Linq's `FirstOrDefault()` to stop iterating as soon as a file is found, so you'll have to add `using System.Linq;`

Note that `FirstOrDefault()` will return null (for strings, as in this example) when there are no items in the sequence.

One important thing to be aware of is that both `Directory.EnumerateFiles()` and `Directory.GetFiles()` will throw exceptions if you attempt to access directories that you aren't allowed to (for example, if you start at the root of C:\, it could attempt to access `C:\$Recycle.Bin` which will cause an exception).

Answer (score 1):

If you have *many* directories and files may *enumerate* them; it could be convenient if you want to *exclude* some directories:

```
public static String FindFileDeep(String path, String fileName) {
  foreach(String file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(path))
    if (String.Equals(Path.GetFileName(file), fileName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
      return file;

  foreach (var dir in Directory.EnumerateDirectories(path)) {
    // You can exclude some directories here:
    // if (...) continue;   

    String result = FindIndexHtml(dir);

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(result))
      return result;
  }

  return null;
}

...

String indexHtml = FindFileDeep(@"C:\MyFiles", "index.html");
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a method that gets the contents of a directory (DirectoryInfo class) that is passed as a parameters.

Cycle through each of the .GetFiles() of the DirectoryInfo to find the flie.

Then, if need be, use the .GetDirectories() list and cycle through them re-calling the same function with the found directory name.

Disclaimer: Uncompiplied/untests - Prototype...

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    FileInfo fi = FindFile("index.html", new DirectoryInfo("C:\\"));
}

static FileInfo FindFile(string Name, DirectoryInfo di)
{
    FileInfo fiFound = null;

    // Try and find it in this directory
    FileInfo[] fiList = di.GetFiles("index.html");


    if (fiList.Length == 0)
    {
        foreach (DirectoryInfo diCycle in di.GetDirectories())
        {
            fiFound = FindFile(Name, diCycle);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        fiFound = fiList.First();
    }

    return (fiFound);
}
```